# "Wipe" or "wipe down" in context?

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

Let's say I am eating ice cream with a friend and the friend got some ice cream on their face. And I point that out so that he will remove it. Do I say

> you have some ice cream on your face, *wipe* it

or

> you have some ice cream on your face, **wipe** it **down**?

Comment: I would say you should use `wipe it` however, I'd more likely use `You have some ice cream on your face, wipe if off`

Comment: Aside: having ice cream on their face might not be obvious, but having pointed that out I would skip the second part: many people don't like being told what to do when it's obvious: it implies that you think they are stupid.

Comment: To add, "wipe it down" means specifically to "clean something by rubbing it with a cloth." In the scenario you gave, your friend would most likely use their hand or a napkin, and so saying "wipe it down" would sound strange.

Comment: @WeatherVane I guess that it is a correct speech to say while you give wipes to your friend, isn't it?

Comment: @EgorRandomize in that case I would say "You have some ice cream on your face, here is a wipe" without insulting them by explaining what it is for.

Comment: In this case your friend can say "I understand" because he can miss your purpose to make his face clear. Or it is complete if you suggest this part instead of Dmytro's the second part

Comment: “Wipe down” is a phrasal verb that is almost always applied to either a flat surface (like a table, kitchen bench or even walls) or the outer surfaces of an object (like a vacuum cleaner, the upholstery of a chair). It is not idiomatic to apply the verb to a person. @HereByAccident: I don’t think what you use to “wipe down” has much to do with it. I can wipe down a sink with a sponge. I can wipe my face with a cloth.